# I am plotting vectors in R in a 2-D cartestian system. My X and Y arrays are unequal in size, so how do I plot my X and Y vectors?

Tags: r, plot, modeling

I am attempting to plot discrete functions in R for a flow model equation.  I have to plot the original function *u(x)* = tanh(*x - 0.1*), with *u(x)* on the Y-axis and *x* on the X-axis.  I then must plot a discrete function that describes the slope.
    u <- array(0,dim=c(21))

```
#Plot the original function u(x)=tanh(ax-x0)
curve(tanh(x-0.1), from=0, to=5, n=100, col="red", xlab="x", ylab = "u(x)")
grid (NULL,NULL, col = "lightgray", lty="dotted") 

x = seq(0, 5, by=0.25)
for (i in 1:21){
u[i] = tanh(x[i]-0.1)
}

x1 = seq(0, 4.75, by=0.25)
du1 <- array(0,dim=c(20))
for (i in 1:20){
du1[i] = (u[i+1]-u[i])/0.25
}

plot(x1, du1, xlab = "x", ylab = "du/dx")
```

So per the definition of my derivative function, my *du/dx* vector will only have 20 vector points, but my *x* vector still has 21 points.  I must then repeat giving defined *du/dx* vectors that have 19 and 18 vector points.  Is there any way I can plot the *du/dx* vs. *x* functions all on the same graph without having to redefine *x* every time?

Comment: I'm not understanding the need to do repeat calculations on diminishing vector sizes. Are you attempting to generate (numerical) estimates of second d( du/dx)/dx) and third d( d( du/dx)/dx)/dx) derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm totally clear on what you're asking, but here's code that prevents you from writing out 18 individual code blocks (using the "diff" function in base).

```
derivs <- matrix(NA, nrow=21, ncol=18)
x <- seq(0, 5, by=0.25)
orig <- tanh(x-0.1)
derivs[,1] <- c(diff(orig)/.25, NA)

for(col in 2:18) {
      print(col)
      derivs[,col] <- c((diff(derivs[,col-1])/.25), NA)
}
```

The resulting matrix (here called "derivs" has a column for each derivative (first column is first derivative, second is second derivative, etc...)

One reason I'm a bit confused about what you're trying for is that, if you were to plot all these on one graph, it would be a really weird graph, because the order of magnitudes are really different between the first few, and the last few derivatives.

The dimensions aren't really different for each derivative; I've simply padded it with NAs, which won't appear on a graph.

Also note that you can use the diff function to get second-order differences and so forth.

PS.  The graph will probably look more reasonable if, rather than taking the differences as you did (and as I did, to emulate you), so that the different is assigned to the first x value...you probably want to center.  E.g. every other derivative would actually be plotted at .125, .375, etc.)